# Scheduled Task to kill specific internet explorer tab

Tags: file, batch-file

Is it possible to schedule a task that will kill a specific internet tab every 15 minutes?

Our operatives all access a reports dashboard, but due to the number of licenses we keep finding ourselves being unable to log on as people leave their screen open despite not using it.

If there was a scheduled task that ran every 15 minutes, perhaps that just kicked off a batch file that looked for an internet tab that's always called 'Dashboard' then it would kill it, that would be great.

Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Comment: You may be able to use an Autoit script to solve this.  They can then be compiled into an exe file and launched in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done easily if it can be done at all.

Does the application you use - Dashboard? - have a setting to handle a session after some time of inactivity as being closed like when closing the page in the browser or terminate the browser?

It would be better to control the session and license management from server side instead of from client side.

Do you use `OpenStack Dashboard (Horizon)` as I found the page [Horizon does not implement a browser session timeout](https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1118441) with the information that there is now such a feature.